# Apache <Location "/baz"> directive not matching

Tags: apache-2.2

I fail to make `<Location "/specific-url/">` works on Apache 2.2 (v2.2.22).

I want to set an HTTP header for the whole site, except for one specific URL path: `/baz` (and `/baz/`, `/baz/quuz`, etc.).

So I've set the following Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    <Location "/">
        Header set X-Foo "bar"
    </Location>
    <Location "/baz">
        Header unset X-Foo
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Header `X-Foo` is indeed returned for non-`/baz` URL:

```
curl -D - https://example.com/qux -o /dev/null -s | grep "X-Foo"
# Outputs:
# X-Foo: bar
```

But, this is where it fails, also for `/baz` URL:

```
curl -D - https://example.com/baz -o /dev/null -s | grep "X-Foo"
# Outputs:
# X-Foo: bar
```

As if `<Location "/">` works but `<Location "/baz">` does not match.

I also tried:

```
<Location "/">
    Header set X-Foo "bar"
</Location>
<Location "/">
    Header unset X-Foo
</Location>
```

And header `X-Foo` is never returned, so `Header unset` does works.

Comment: It won't work the way you're trying. You should look at using negated LocationMatch. Set the header to everything except /baz, rather than set and unset.

Comment: I've found http://serverfault.com/questions/591591/apache-locationmatch-regex-behaviour-does-not-seem-correct which suggests set and unset. `<LocationMatch "^/baz/">` matches `/baz` and `/baz/` but does not `/baz/sub`.

Comment: Also tried to only set header with `<LocationMatch ^/(?!(baz($|/.*)))>`: it is set for all URL but "/baz" and "/baz/", I want subdirs of /baz not to get the header.

Comment: I don't see where the above link suggests unset.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Apache 2.0 manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header):

> The Header directives are processed just before the response is sent
>   to the network.

In other words, `Header set X-Foo "bar"` is applied only **after** everything has been processed already and the response is about to be sent. In the same way, `Header unset X-Foo` is applied (or removed) only if the header already exists in the response to begin with - for example if the application sends it.

As I've suggested, what you need in fact is to rethink the problem from a different angle. Instead of trying to set and then unset, just apply the set to *all* less what you want to exclude. The following will work:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!baz)">
    Header always set X-Foo "bar"
</LocationMatch>
```

`X-Foo: bar` will be set to all requests, less:
/baz
/baz/
/baz/abcd*

Also, mind the extra `always` directive which applies the header to non successful responses as well.

Comment: I works for existing (physically, on disk) directory `baz/images` (I don't get the header when accessing https://example.com/baz/images/: correct) but it does not works for https://example.com/baz/list (I get the header: incorrect), an URL that get caught by my application (in PHP, via a `FallbackResource /index.php` directive): I thought `Location*` worked on accessed URL, no matter what's behind it (static file, mod_php, proxy, etc.).

Comment: I now understand my issue comes from dynamic content URLs and existing directories conflict making <Location> directive not working: should I accept this answer and create a new question more explicit with context of dynamic content and existing directories?